# Rabbitmq federated queue with mirror

Tags: rabbitmq, load-balancing, high-availability

I am new to **RabbitMQ** and not too sure if my goal is achievable. Basically, my goal is to be able to setup a **highly available** and **load balanced queues**.

So given **3** nodes with **1** queue each (let's say `Node1` has `Queue1, Queue2, Queue3`. `Node2` also has `Queue1, Queue2, Queue3`, and the same for `Node3`). **Each queue has it's own consumer**.

*I would like to load balance the messages in the queues so that producers can send the message to any of the queue and get the consumer to process the queue.*

I would also like to **implement mirroring** so that if one of the `Nodes` goes down (lets say `Node1` goes down for some reason), the messages sent to queues in `Node1` will **not** be lost and will still be processed.

From my understanding in Clustering, messages are stored to where the master queue is so therefore I didn't achieved the load balanced queue that I want.

Is my goal achievable? If yes, how can I do that?

I was looking at Federated queues but not too sure if I can implement mirroring with it.

Thanks.
GGarcia

Answer (score 2):

According to this no, it's not possible:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2013/10/23/federated-queues-in-3-2-0/

'Federated queues will only ever contain a given message in one location; there's no mirroring.'

I've been thinking, what about implementing federated queues, and providing HA to every node using a 'low level' solution like Pacemaker/DRBD?

https://www.rabbitmq.com/pacemaker.html

Haven't tried it, it's just an idea.

The other thing to try is maybe using sharding instead of federated queues, here it says it should be possible to mirror its sharded queues:

https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-sharding/issues/12

Good luck!